# Tradução de página do Woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Meu Woocommerce já está todinho traduzido. Porém, a página "Minha Conta" está com o menu assim:

Dashboard
My Orders
Edit Account
Edit Address
Logout

Alguém sabe como traduzir? Não sei nem que código poderia postar aqui como referência...rs

Answer (score 2):

Como você fez a tradução? Automática pelo WordPress?
Porque quando você instala o WordPress em pt-br, já vem todo traduzido.

Mas enfim, de qualquer forma, existe uma forma de traduzir, que eu uso.

Existe um plugin chamado **Loco Translate**.

1. Instale e ative o mesmo.
2. Nas configurações do mesmo, você terá a opção de escolher o arquivo, sendo de tema ou plugin.
3. Escolha plugin e WooCommerce, crie um template para a linguagem do seu WordPress.
4. Verifique se é o plugin do WooCommerce que precisa de tradução buscando as palavras não traduzidas.
5. Se for, salve e verifique se foi traduzido.
6. Se não, verifique se é o tema.

Comment: Descobri! Era um plug-in!! :/

Comment: Mesmo assim, muito obrigada!